# how to import existing sample apps in the salesforce android sdk into eclipse?

Tags: salesforce

i m trying to  integrate salesforce with mobile apps for that i downloaded salesforce android sdk cloning from GITHUB.

I just wanted to know run a sample application to understand the functionality once but while importing an existing project into workspace i m getting this warning

WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Documents and Settings\haripriya.madduri\SalesforceMobileSDK-Android\native\SampleApps\RestExplorer\bin\jarlist.cache

could you tell me what is missed and what is the procedure clearly..Any suggestions

Thanks

Comment: You can ask Salesforce questions directly on salesforce.stackexchange.com